Prove that convex hull of two non-coinciding ellipses of equal area and with coinciding centers contains ellipse of larger area
Two ellipses of equal area (but not necessarily equal eccentricity) are not coinciding but share common center. Prove that their convex hull contains ellipse that is larger by area than both those ellipses or find counterexample.
Note that statement is not true if areas of two ellipses are not equal, example is shown on picture below, ellipse $O$ is the largest ellipse that is inscribed in rectangle, touching it at middles of rectangle sides. Ellipse $O’$ is smaller ellipse inscribed in same rectangle along diagonal, their convex hull is contained in rectangle and thus cannot contain ellipse larger than $O$.


We place orthogonal coordinate system so that origin coincides with common center of two ellipses and $y-$axis is along bisector of two half-axes of different ellipses (no matter which half-axis from each ellipse to choose).
We can stretch or squeeze two ellipses along $y-$axis till angle between chosen half-axes is $90°$, this is always possible because in a limit when stretching this angle converges to $0°$ and when squeezing it converges to $180°$. In case when ellipses already have orthogonal half-axes, we do not need to do this transform.
Now we can choose smaller of the two orthogonal half-axes belonging to different ellipses and stretch both ellipses along this direction from origin till ellipses have equal eccentricity. We will get two equal ellipses with common center and one ellipse rotated by $90°$ with respect to another as on picture below.
These two orthogonal ellipses can be inscribed into square as on picture, and they cannot coincide with biggest ellipse that can be inscribed into same square, which is inner circle of this square (shown on picture), because they are not coinciding one with another.
This inner circle is contained in convex hull of these two orthogonal ellipses. This implies that preimage of inner circle with respect to linear transform applied to both initial ellipses is also contained in convex hull of two initial ellipses while its area is larger than area of each initial ellipse ∎

